# Media uploads error

Tags: uploads, media

I am very new to this and just created my site yesterday. Suddenly I can’t upload any photos and an error is being displayed ‘An error occurred in the upload. Please try again later’. I saw a suggestion to use the console and its giving a error saying mixed content and that my page was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet tp://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dancing+Script&ver=4.9.8’. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

Is your website set to load over https? So https://example.com and not http://example.com?

The link to google fonts is over http which will cause an error when your site loads securely over https.

There are a few places the reference to google fonts could be: try header.php, functions.php and your stylesheet(s).  Wherever you find a reference to “http://fonts.googleapis.com” change it to “https://fonts.googleapis.com” or just “//fonts.googleapis.com”.

This should fix the error in the console but there are a number of other things which could be stopping media from being uploaded. Try the above and then try it again.